# Error when checking input: expected lstm_28_input to have shape (5739, 8) but got array with shape (1, 8)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, keras-layer, attention-model

i got keras dimension error

the input shape is like this

```
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
```

result

```
(5739, 1, 8) (5739,) (1435, 1, 8) (1435,)
```

and model is belows

```
batch_size=128
epochs=20
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention
from keras.layers import Flatten
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(epochs, input_shape=(train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

result

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_33 (LSTM)               (None, 5739, 20)          2320      
_________________________________________________________________
seq_self_attention_35 (SeqSe (None, 5739, 20)          1345      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_8 (Flatten)          (None, 114780)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 114781    
=================================================================
Total params: 118,446
Trainable params: 118,446
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

but i got error in fit step

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_33_input to have shape (5739, 8) but got array with shape (1, 8)
```

but i print input shape which is (5739,8), and i can't understand where (1,8) is coming from. and how to fix it.

```
input_shape=(train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[2])
print(input_shape)
(5739, 8)
```

is it problem of input shape in test_X, test_Y or train?
and how should i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An LSTM layer in Keras expects batches of data with shape `(n_timesteps, n_features)`. You are constructing your layer with the wrong dimensions.

First, reshape your training data to the shape `n_data_points, n_timesteps, n_features`:

```
train_X_ = np.swapaxes(train_X, 1, 2)
train_X_.shape # now of shape (5739, 8, 1)
```

Then specify your model with the correct dimensions:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
# input shape for the LSTM layer will be (8,1). No need to specify the batch shape.
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(20, input_shape=(train_X_.shape[1], train_X_.shape[2]), return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

This will work properly:

```
model.fit(train_X_, train_y)
```

Comment: thank you for help! but it is not working if i add SeqSelfAttention layer. how should i do?

Comment: The SeqSelfAttention layer is not implemented in Keras, so I cannot help you with that here; I suggest that you ask a different question and specify the repository where this layer is implemented.

Comment: from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention i used this package is it not for keras?

Comment: It's from an external library: https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-self-attention. If your problem is non-trivial I would suggest you post a question on the github issues there.

Comment: Although based on the examples in the repo, I think you just need to remove your `Flatten()` layer.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it:)